# how to show a backorder status in woocommerce orders listing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We have a lot of backorders in WooCommerce and we would like to be able to sort all the backorders in the orders table.

Currently, we are filtering the orders using these status: Awaiting shipment, Refunded, Cancelled, Completed,  Processing

Please refer to the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOrsr.jpg)

I've searched online and I only found [a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-backorders-for-woocommerce/) that create a separate menu link lisitng backorders only.

Is there a filter I could add in functions.php that would do the job ? I don't want to install a plugin just for that.

Right Now i've only been able to add a custom backorder status using this code below, the second step would be to trigger the status when there is a backordered product.

```
/** 
 * Register new status
 * Tutorial: http://www.sellwithwp.com/woocommerce-custom-order-status-2/
**/
function register_backorders_order_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-backorders', array(
        'label'                     => 'Backorders',
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'backorders <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Awaiting shipment <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_backorders_order_status' );
// Add to list of WC Order statuses
function add_backorders_to_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $new_order_statuses = array();
    // add new order status after processing
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;
        if ( 'wc-processing' === $key ) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-backorders'] = 'Backorders';
        }
    }
    return $new_order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_backorders_to_order_statuses' );
```

Comment: `_n_noop( 'backorders <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Awaiting shipment <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )` you have used backorders(singular) and Awaiting Shipment(plural)? Is for backorder or awaiting shipment? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_n_noop

Comment: it is for back orders